# What is causing the model to null

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Angular Service:-

```
app.service('loginService', ['$http', function ($http) {

this.userLogin = function (user) {
   console.log(user); //prints {'username': 'username@gmail.com', 'password': 123'}
    $http(
   {
       url: "/api/user/login",
       method: "POST",
       data: { 'model': user },
       contentType: "application/json"
   })
   .then(function (data) {
       if (data.status.toLower() === "success") {
           return data;
       }
       else {
           return null;
       }
   });
}
```

Angular Controller

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', function ($scope, loginService) {
$scope.login = function (user) {
    debugger;
    console.log($scope.user);
    var data = loginService.userLogin($scope.user);
}
```

}]);

WebAPI.

```
[Route("api/user/login")]
    public void Post([FromBody]LoginVM model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

But when I debug the WebAPI model it has all the values as null.

My LoginVM class

```
 [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Why I am getting the properties as null?

Comment: post the controller

Comment: @sachilaranawaka, controller already posted.#WebAPI

Comment: Try sending  user object directly like `data: user,` in your service call

Comment: have you confirmed at the network tag to see whether your data is send successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Your passing your content type header incorrectly. It get's passed as part of the headers parameter like so:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/user/login",
    method: "POST",
    data: { 'model': user },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}).then(function (data) {
   if (data.status.toLower() === "success") {
        return data;
   } else {
       return null;
   }
});
```

However, unless you have changed the default headers you don't even need to pass the content type. [See the default headers in the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers).

So you can simply make your request like so:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/user/login",
    method: "POST",
    data: { 
        model: user 
    }
}).then(function (data) {
   if (data.status.toLower() === "success") {
        return data;
   } else {
       return null;
   }
});
```

And you shouldn't need the `[FromBody]` Attribute on your method because your `LoginVM` is a complex type (Class).

**Also, I've had it in the past where sometimes visual studio plays up and it's not debugging correctly. It's worth closing visual studio and re-opening it if that's the IDE you're using.**

Comment: @Kgn-web Try just sending `data: user` instead of `data: {model: user}`

Comment: @Kgn-web You said console.log(user) prints :`{'username': 'username@gmail.com', 'password': 123'}` it should print `{'username': 'username@gmail.com', 'password': '123'}` note the missing quote mark on the 123

Comment: @ cnorthfield 2 Yes. It is let me share my controller as well

Comment: @Kgn-web try matching the case of the object properties before sending it in the Ajax request ("Username" instead of "username")

Comment: @Alex, I had decorated my class with `[Serializable]`  attribute, when I removed this attribute, model started getting values. But still I am thinking how does marking a class  `[Serializable]`  attribute makes difference? Please add  your thoughts on this, if you can Thanks.