# How does decorating a class with `[Serializable]` attribute makes difference?

Tags: c#, angularjs, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Taking my below question further,

[What is causing the model to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874201/what-is-causing-the-model-to-null)

I spend more than 3 hours on finding out the cause. As just part of hit-try process I removed `[Serializable]` from my class & the surprisingly model started getting values.

Angular Service:-

```
app.service('loginService', ['$http', function ($http) {

this.userLogin = function (user) {
   console.log(user); //prints {'username': 'username@gmail.com', 'password': 123'}
    $http(
   {
       url: "/api/user/login",
       method: "POST",
       data: { 'model': user },
       contentType: "application/json"
   })
   .then(function (data) {
       if (data.status.toLower() === "success") {
           return data;
       }
       else {
           return null;
       }
   });
}
```

Angular Controller

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'loginService', function ($scope, loginService) {
$scope.login = function (user) {
    debugger;
    console.log($scope.user);
    var data = loginService.userLogin($scope.user);
}
```

WebAPI.

```
[Route("api/user/login")]
    public void Post([FromBody]LoginVM model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

But when I debug the WebAPI model it has all the values as null.

My Initial LoginVM class

```
   [Serializable]
   public class LoginVM 
   {
   [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
   }
```

Following two updates fixed my issue.

## 1

```
   //[Serializable] removed this attribute
   public class LoginVM 
   {
   [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
   }
```

## 2

```
 $http(
   {
       url: "/api/user/login",
       method: "POST",
       data:  user , // directly passed user object to API
       contentType: "application/json"
   })
```

I am trying to understand how does decorating a class with [Serializable] attribute & directly passing object makes difference??

In case I need to pass multiple parameters then how will I pass then??

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Web Api treats `Serializable` attribute [specifically](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/04/11/json-net-4-5-release-2-serializable-support-and-bug-fixes):

> Json.NET now detects types that have the SerializableAttribute and
>   serializes all the fields on that type, both public and private, and
>   ignores the properties. This is useful when you’re interested in
>   round-tripping the data on a type and don’t care what the JSON looks
>   like.

If you need to keep `Serializable` attribute - you can decorate your model with a plain `JsonObject` attribute:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class LoginVM 
{
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Here what you mean by round-tripping ?? Please add. Thanks

Comment: I think important part for your case is **when you’re ... don’t care what the JSON looks like**. I've added workaround to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I am going through the link shared.

Comment: @Kgn-web, if my answer solved your problem - please accept it.

Comment: Sure. I will do. I was occupied by something else. I have completed reading of the link but needs verify in my case. I have upvoted your ans & I will make sure to accept once post to rightly address the issue.